# Calling Rest services with various securities from MULE HTTP ENDPOINT

Tags: rest, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

i have a requirement, i want to call list of REST services which have different security mechanisms, like, some may have HTTPS and others may have naked HTTP, few others may have basic authentication and remaining may require a "Authorization header"  . i want to call all these REST services with different service mechanism from a single HTTP OUT BOUND END POINT . how can i  configure the HTTP endpoint to accomplish this  ? or  should i use different end points to accomplish my requirement .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different service mechanism requires different configuration...

If you want to do it in a single flow, as Victor said you need to use choice router and based on certain condition it will call the rest service it required...

and in each Choice block, you have to configure the calling of each type of rest service with it's security mechanism

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Some of the attributes of the Http connector/endpoints can be configured as an expression but not all of them.

You'll have to leverage a choice-router and a number of http and https endpoints.